# How can I use Sin⁻¹ in C# equations?

Tags: c#, equation

I wrote a equation to calculate a variable's value in c#, but it has sin⁻¹ in it and I can't find anything about how to write this function in c#. Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried finding the sin of the number first and then putting that to the power of -1 to see if it would get me the sin⁻¹ of the number. That didn't work since Sin(blank)⁻¹ and Sin⁻¹(blank) aren't the same thing, and got me a number unrelated to the equation I was trying to recreate.
The Equation I'm replicating is here: y=cos(sin⁻¹(x))
So far I have this as my code, I replaced Sin⁻¹ with Sin:

```
debugVariable2 = (int)(Math.Cos(Math.Sin(ballRotation)));
```

If there is no sin⁻¹ function, does anyone know how to get the same results of sin⁻¹ using math functions in C# or any libraries that add it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.asin?view=net-7.0

Comment: If by "`sin⁻¹`" you mean _inverse-of-sine_ then that's also known as [Arcsine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions), which is `Math.Asin` in C#/.NET. But if you meant the _reciprocal-of-sine_ then that's just `(1 / Math.Sin(x))`